# Parsing the RTP Header and Payload from the received RT packets

Tags: c, rtp

I am working on developing a soft-phone, for this I am implementing my own module. I am able to successfully send the RTP packets to my SIP Server and on the other hand I am getting RTP packets, from which I need to parse the header and payload.

I know that the length of the RTP header is 12 and after that follows the payload. Now can somebody shed some light of how to parse header and payload. I am working with C as programming language.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to follow the [RFC3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) and then to look at the corresponding RFC for the payload type. Another link you could look at is http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/rtp.htm. It also contains links to the various RFCs.

Alternatively if you want some example code as a starting point, there are loads of open source RTP libraries in both c and c++ that you could have a look at. [LiveMedia](http://www.live555.com), [jRtpLib](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/%7Ejori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib), [RtpLib](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/irt/software/rtplib/) are some you could use but there were tons more.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I am already following the RFC 3550, but I am looking for a sample implementation of how I can validate the RTP constant header, in case somebody can direct me would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by validate? For a example of how to parse the header, have a look at the live555 library: it contains source for parsing both the RTP header and various payload formats.